# protoype call function via "this" return "is not a function"

Tags: javascript

need help understanding clousures and prototypes, i'm calling a loop method inside a function, the problem is , when i call the "loop" returns "is not a function" here's the example:

```
window.onload= startGame();

var theGame;

function startGame(){
   theGame = new game();
   theGame.loop(); /*im calling the method*/

}

function game(){
    this.canvas=document.getElementById("breakout");
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
    this.canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
   // this.loop(); /*¿can i call it here too?*/
    this.speed = 100;

}

game.prototype.loop = function() {

    console.log( this.speed+=1);

    var self = this;
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){ 
            self.loop();
        });  

};
```

**when i call the "LOOP" method the browsers errors 
"Uncaught TypeError: theGame.loop is not a function "**

Comment: It needs to be `window.onload= startGame;`, without calling the function there.

Comment: Question about problems related to calling a function prematurely have been asked so many times. I think we need a canonical Q&A for this (or at least determine which one of the existing ones it should be).

Comment: Or move `startGame()` to the end, after defining `game.prototype.loop`.

Comment: @FelixKling, would it be better to write a new question/canonical answer that draws on all the general information from the preceding questions/answers to quickly summarise the issue? Another Q: do you know if canonical answers rise to the top of searches/rank better than similar questions?

Comment: @Andy: I feel like for some issues, such as this one, it's difficult for a canonical Q&A to come into existence organically (not planned), simply because in most cases the question itself is about a symptom of the problem, not the actual problem (like here). OTOH, a canonical Q&A is helpful the most if it can be found by looking for symptoms of the problem, and for this one, there might just be too many. As for ranking: I don't know how it works. I assume (hope) they take into account views and upvotes (and canonical Q&A should have many upvotes), but that assumes the search terms match well.

Comment: @Oriol That would not help and would simply lead to other issues, like the DOM not being ready.

Comment: @plalx [That *would* help](https://jsfiddle.net/d2oa0fc8/). If the DOM is not ready, `DOMContentLoaded` event should be used instead of `load`.

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` is the right answer. jsfiddle puts the JS code in the body after the HTML by default. That's the only reason it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are incorrectly setting up the onload event handler since you are calling the function right away instead of simply referencing it.

```
window.onload= startGame();
```

Should be:

```
window.onload = startGame;
```